# Consolidating information in two rows in MySQL query result

Tags: mysql

I have table which looks like this (example)

```
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
| id | objectId | filterId | filterValueId |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
|  1 |       55 |      111 |          2345 |
|  2 |       55 |      113 |          2567 |
|  3 |       55 |      113 |          2568 |
|  4 |       58 |      111 |          2347 |
|  5 |       58 |      115 |          2499 |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Now, I have query with some LEFT JOINs (main object table, this filter table, meta table and few others). I am creating frontend filtering and I got to the point where it sort of works, but I am stuck at one problem.

When I have two filters in the queue (lets say *filterId=>filterValueId* 111=>2345 and 113=>2567).
With query

```
SELECT ojectId IN tableName
 WHERE (filterId = 111 AND filterValueId = 2345) 
   AND (filterId = 113 AND filterValeId = 2567)
```

I am not able to get out the information, that objectId 55 is matching both these criteria. at least not in single query. It makes sense, I know, but is there a way making MySQL to give such result? (And does this request/procedure have some technical name I could use for googling?)

Or is it best practice to split such filtering into many queries and then intersect results and get out just these which are in every result?

Sorry for using technical terms in wrong way, hopefully sou can understand what I am trying to say :)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,objectId INT NOT NULL
,filterId INT NOT NULL
,filterValueId INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,55,111,2345),
(2,55,113,2567),
(3,55,113,2568),
(4,58,111,2347),
(5,58,115,2499);

SELECT objectid 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE (filterid,filtervalueid) IN ((111,2345),(113,2567)) 
 GROUP 
    BY objectid 
HAVING COUNT(id = 2);
+----------+
| objectid |
+----------+
|       55 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Hi, i admit the question was probably to vague. But your answer pointed me the right direction anyway, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No special name to search in google. You just wrote your fetching sql to only fetch one record instead of two, by using `AND`. You should use `OR`.
And correct `IN` to `FROM`.

```
SELECT ojectId 
FROM tableName 
WHERE 
    (filterId = 111 AND filterValueId = 2345) 
    OR (filterId = 113 AND filterValeId = 2567)
```

> Or is it best practice to split such filtering into many queries and
>   then intersect results and get out just these which are in every
>   result?

NO! Let database to work hard and good only once. Give it all filters at once. No need to split queries.

Comment: This is only half the answer

Comment: @Strawberry I read the question twice, again. Imho I answered to the whole question. What have I missed?

Comment: My answer covers it.

Comment: @Strawberry You're kidding, right? :-))))))  Am I blind? I read again. Nothing!!!

Comment: The question posed (albeit a little ambiguously) is 'which objectid matches *both* criteria'.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh... Well, not conform to the whole phrase: "_I am not able to get out the information, that objectId 55 is matching both these criteria. at least not in single query._". But I give up :-) Too abstract question form.